# Чем можно заменить for event in VkBotLongPoll(token, groupid).listen()?

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

Используется Python3 и модуль vk_api

Чтож, это странный вопрос, но мне хочется заменить привычную

```
import vk_api

token = ''
groupid = 43545764

vk = vk_api.VkApi(token = token)
for event in VkBotLongPoll(vk, groupid).listen(): #эту строку
    pass
```

на какую-либо альтернативу. Возможно ли это?

Comment: Можно заменить ручным выполнением запроса. Есть метод API для получения событий. Но зачем?

Comment: @nomnoms12 Всё просто. С использованием этого цикла я не могу использовать какие-либо другие процессы в коде. Весь код будет ждать событие, которое произойдёт в сообществе, даже если использовать threading или multiproccessering.